# input['file'] accept="image/*" open dialog so slow with Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I use `<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>` with Chrome, it opens the dialog very slowly (more than 10s on Mac 10.11.6 with Chrome 52.0.2743.116 64-bit).

But when I remove `accept="image/*"`, it becomes right. And I’ve look at my Facebook page, it works fine. What's different?

[image: Facebook input]

Stack Overflow's picture upload also becomes so slow with my Chrome.

[image: Stack Overflow]

What happens to my Chrome? I’ve tested other’s Chrome, it’s OK…

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. (That's why I happened to searched into this page.)

Comment: @ykan This is confirmed as a bug in Chrome. Please check the update of my answer. Fortunately, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE in Jul. 2017:** This is confirmed as a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638874) in Chrome, and it is [fixed](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/514582/) now.

The root cause of this bug is: Chrome's *SafeBrowsing* feature will check file on uploading or saving. If the internet connection to google's server is fast, it's OK. But if the connection is slow or broken, *SafeBrowsing* will make Chrome hang for a few seconds, until the check is finished or timeout.

Using `accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"` will workaround this issue because MIME types `image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif` are in the whitelist of  *SafeBrowsing* -- no check is needed. However, for `accept="image/*"` or `accept=".apk"`, as it's not in the whitelist, *SafeBrowsing* will trigger the check and hang Chrome.

This bug has been [fixed](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/514582/) by skip the check on uploading.

Note: I get the above information from a Chinese [article](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/27946188) written by Wang Lei, who is inspired by @cute_ptr's answer. Thanks to Wang Lei and I think @cute_ptr's answer deserve an upvote.

---

UPDATE: Thanks to @xiefei's comment, the **final workaround** would be:
`<input type="file" name="imgFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">`. If necessary, other image MIME types can be appended.

---

This bug is reproduced on my machine: Mac + Chrome + `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`. It seems like a Chrome bug on Mac when `accept` attribute is used, as it's not reproduced on Windows environment, or on other browsers.

Comment: No. Adding `name` attribute does not workaround this bug.

Comment: This bug may appear under the combination of several conditions. One way to find solution/workaround is: find a web page whose "image upload" behaviour is OK, then compare their HTML code with our own, normally the HTML code difference will provide the answer.

Comment: @xiefei I've reproduced this bug on some other Mac+Chrome environment, where `name` attribute does not help. One workaround is figured out: use specific image MIME types, rather than image/*. That is: `<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">`.

Comment: Yes. use "image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" does help. Thank you very much. But I am encounting another problem:  I am using `accept=".apk"` on another file input and the dialog opens slowly again, any suggestion?

Comment: @xiefei, I can reproduce your problem, but can't find a workaround... tried `accept=".apk, .apk"` but it does not work (also found it violate HTML specification). Sorry...

Comment: Yes, if not use `accept="image/*"`, it works fine. But why just facebook's page still works well....I can't find anything different...

Comment: yes...it is pretty weird that plain `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` works fine on facebook, while it is slow on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "image/*" is slow on windows 10, chrome 53 as well, I switched to "image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" and it works well!

Comment: @xiefei `accept=".apk"` will make dialog open slowly because `.apk` is not in the whitelist of SafeBrowsing. Please check the update of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I Think I may have found the reason, at least on my machine:

When my internet connection is on, it opens fast the file dialog, when I turn it off, it is slow, then I turn it on again and it is fast again.

Therefore try opening the file dialog when your internet connection is on, and see if there is any difference. It worked for me.

Comment: I have updated my Chrome, and problem has gone. In my case, my internet connection is always on...

Comment: @ykan maybe your internet connection to google's server was slow or broken?

Answer (score 0):

From the best answer, we have known this is a chrome bug and ready to be fixed. Until today(2017/08/23), chrome 60.0.3112.101 has not fixed this bug yet. However latest chrome canary(62.0.3194.0) has fixed it.