# xp:fileUpload preload possible?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have several xp:fileUpload on a form. I notice that it takes a long time to get the Open dialog to explore after a file. Is there a possibility to speed up the process?

There is the loaded property but that is default already true.

Or is there another setting that is lagging the appearance of the explorer dialog?

Comment: xp:fileUpload uses the standard HTML <input type="file"..>. Maybe it's a browser bug?

Comment: are the fileUploads in a repeat control?

Comment: Do you have an "accept" attribute in your <input type="file"..>? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187857/inputfile-accept-image-open-dialog-so-slow-with-chrome